# Unable to get current route path or name in Vue JS 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I am trying to get current route by using below piece of code.

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute();
console.log(JSON.stringify(route));
console.log(route.path);
```

But I unable to get exact rout path, any route i push, i only getting '/' in my route path..

[image]

Any reason, why i unable to get my route name?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown where and under which conditions you do this

Comment: _"any route i push"_ how are you doing this?  If it's important to reproduce the problem, then it is prudent to include the relevant code in your question. Other information such as your routes definition and other relevant route related code should be included.

Comment: where the code above running,you shuld add the context because the route  is what depend on the context.

Comment: Also, can you share the content of your route? This would better help in providing an answer for your trouble.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do:
const router = useRouter();

Then you can get current page name with this code:
router.currentRoute.value.name

and get current route path with this code:
router.currentRoute.value.path

Comment: const router = useRouter();
console.log(router.currentRoute.value.path);

Comment: route.currentRoute returning undefined for me.

Comment: Route does not have a currentRoute attribute. You should first declare const router = useRouter();
and then use router.currentRoute.value.path;

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you have to define the route name inside your route file like this:

```
path: "/login",
name: "login",
```

from what i see, you don't define your route name inside your route file.

After that you can use the `useRoute` hooks to get the route name.

For example:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

const route = useRoute()

// Will return the route name
console.log(route.name)
```

You can check more examples in this [official docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api)

Comment: I defined my route name, I can able to navigate to my route pages, but only unable to get the route name or path. 
also, your suggestion is not working as well, its returning undefined,

Comment: can you give me your route file code ? let me see it